# What is the purpose of backgroundworker in c#?

Tags: c#

I am kind of new to c# and I am required to create a client server chat. Our professor gave us the following as a small hint to get us going. But I do not understand what the backgroundworker does.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) // Receive data
{
    while (client.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            receive = streamreader.ReadLine();
            this.textBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { textBox2.AppendText("You : " + receive + "\n"); }));
            receive = "";
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) // Send data
{
    if (client.Connected)
    {
        streamwriter.WriteLine(text_to_send);
        this.textBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { textBox2.AppendText("Me : " + text_to_send + "\n"); }));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Send failed!");
    }
    backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BackgroundWorker class is designed to execute operations on a seperate thread, whilst reporting to the main thread through the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) events.
The example your professor provided is far from a typical implementation of the class, and a backgroundworker should probably not be used for something like that.

Comment: So how can this help me for the client-server chat application?

Comment: On top of that you really don't want to use BackgroundWorker anymore (part of EAP). You should use TAP. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938%28v=vs.110%29.aspx